# How to make Route work in all blades in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a route that calls a URL that works normally while on the home page,
when I go to any other page of my project it doesn't work anymore because the URL that
step on the route is being added to the existing routine,

like this: https://makesignin.com/report/employees

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="employees"> Employees </a>
```

A route like this:

```
Route::resource ('employees', 'EmployeesController');
```

what I wish: https://makesignin.com/employees

What do I need to do?

Comment: Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).  Please translate your title into English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a href="/employees"> Employees </a>
```

instead of

```html
<a href="employees"> Employees </a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much and for working for me. 
I appreciate your time!